# How to handle/chain synchronous side effects that depend on another with React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to rewrite my application from redux to the new context + hooks, but unfortunately I'm having a hard finding a good way to handle series of synchronous side-effects that are depending on the response of the previous.

In my current redux application I make heavy use of synchronous/chained actions and API requests which I typically handle through redux-saga or thunks. So when the response of the first API request is returned, that data is used for the next API request etc.

I've made a custom hook "useFetch" (in this example it does not do much, since it's a simplified version, also I had to make a small adjustment for it to work on codesandbox - see the code below). The problem with that is that due to the "rules of hooks", I cannot use a custom hook inside the useEffect hook. So how to await the response of the first request before doing the next etc, if you have your own hook for fetching data? And even if I ended up giving up on useFetch abstraction and create a vanilla fetch request, how to avoid ending up with a bloated mess of many useEffects hooks? Can this be done a little more elegantly, or is context + hooks still to premature to compete with redux saga/thunk for handling side effects?

The example code below is kept very simple. What it should try to simulate is that:

1. query person api endpoint to get the person
2. once we have the person
   response, query the job endpoint (using the person id in real world
   scenario)
3. once we have the person and job, based on the response
   from the person and job endpoints, query the collegues endpoint to
   find the persons collegues at a specific job.

Here's the code. Added a delay to useFetch hook to simulate latency in real world:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const useFetch = (url, delay = 0) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      // const result = await fetch(url, {
      //  method: "GET",
      //  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      // });
      //const response = await result.json();
      const response = await import(url);
      setTimeout(function() {
        setData(response);
      }, delay);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return data;
};

function App() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState();
  const [job, setJob] = useState();
  const [collegues, setCollegues] = useState();

  // first we fetch the person /api/person based on the jwt most likely
  const personData = useFetch("./person.json", 5000);
  // now that we have the person data, we use the id to query for the
  // persons job /api/person/1/jobs
  const jobData = useFetch("./job.json", 3000);
  // now we can query for a persons collegues at job x /api/person/1/job/1/collegues
  const colleguesData = useFetch("./collegues.json", 1000);

  console.log(personData);
  console.log(jobData);
  console.log(colleguesData);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   setPerson(useFetch("./person.json", 5000));
  // }, []);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   setJob(useFetch("./job.json", 3000));
  // }, [person]);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   setCollegues(useFetch("./collegues.json",1000));
  // }, [job]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Running example: https://codesandbox.io/s/2v44lron3n?fontsize=14 (you might need to make a change - space or remove a semicolon - to make it work)

Hopefully something like this (or a better solution) is possible, or I will simply not be able to migrate from the awesome redux-saga/thunks to context + hooks.

**Best Answer:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y55rLsSNUiM

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hooks wont replace the way you handle async actions, they are just an abstraction to some things you were used to do, like calling `componentDidMount`, or handling `state`, etc.

In the example you are giving, you don't really need a custom hook:

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const job = await import("./job.json");
      const collegues = await import("./collegues.json");
      const person = await import("./person.json");
      setData({
        job,
        collegues,
        person
      })
    };
    fetchData()
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
}
```

That being said, maybe if you provide an example of an actual redux-saga or thunks code you have, that you want to refactor, we can see what the steps are to accomplish that.

Edit:

That being said if you still want to do something like this, you can take a look at this:

https://github.com/dai-shi/react-hooks-async

```
import React from 'react';

import { useFetch } from 'react-hooks-async/dist/use-async-task-fetch';

const UserInfo = ({ id }) => {
  const url = `https://reqres.in/api/users/${id}?delay=1`;
  const { pending, error, result, abort } = useFetch(url);
  if (pending) return <div>Loading...<button onClick={abort}>Abort</button></div>;
  if (error) return <div>Error:{error.name}{' '}{error.message}</div>;
  if (!result) return <div>No result</div>;
  return <div>First Name:{result.data.first_name}</div>;
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <UserInfo id={'1'} />
    <UserInfo id={'2'} />
  </div>
);
```

**EDIT**

This is an interesting approach https://swr.now.sh/#dependent-fetching

Comment: Hi Luciano. Thanks. I did however state that I the .json file was just a replacement for this example to get it compiling in codesandbox - so you should NOT rely on import over fetch. Fetch is indeed necessary, since outside the running codesandbox example it will be an api endpoint/url and not a json file. Also what I tried to illustrate with useFetch is abstracting some reuseable code to tell a little something about the status of the request such as isLoading and isError. Using many raw fetch inside useEffect and putting them all inside one big spaghetti useEffect is not a good option

Comment: What im trying to say is that `fetchData` function could call the different apis you need, you can process your data and eventually set it in the state the way you want. It's the same as doing `dispatch('ASYNC_ACTION',...)` and taking it from a saga.. This doesn't change when using hooks + context. You just need to create an async function and call it. Chaining async actions is just that, regardless of importing from a json or calling the real api.

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable with this approach, you can try the early implementations of redux + hooks, and you can dispatch your async actions and use thunks or sagas to handle them the same way you did before. Here is an example of an early implementation https://github.com/facebookincubator/redux-react-hook, but as you stated that you want hooks+context, really the only difference is that instead of dispatching an action you are going to call a function and wait until it resolves, then setState accordingly. Chaining them is like chaining any promise

Comment: Finally, very soon you will see react-redux adding a `userRedux` hook, they had to refactor a lot of things before being able to work on this. So maybe, in a bit you wont even need to replace redux at all: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v7.0.1

Comment: Not going back to Redux, but thanks a lot for some great advice. Really helped me look at the problem a little differently. Now I just need to figure out which of the 3 great answers helped me the most, and accept that one. Only problem with yours is that I want to avoid multiple fetch inside useEffect, therefore the useFetch hook, that in reality would return isLoading and isError feedback in addition to the data. But helpful nonetheless :-)

Comment: I edited my answer, i found something it may be useful for you - good luck

Comment: Accepted your answer, although none of them were fully helping me solve my problem. Your update does not address the issue where you have to await and use the response of the firrst request before you send the next. You would not be able to do that with the hook.

Comment: Im not completely sure this is a good way to do it, but check here https://codesandbox.io/s/yvm1r5q22v?fontsize=14
Basically, you wouldn't await, but instead you need to use the previous async action response as a dependency for the next, and so on. (In the first example in the sandbox using useMemo, the second example using that third party i linked in the answer..)... The key is in the dependencies array.. so you can "tell" the useAsync or useFetch to execute at the right time

Comment: Thanks but I actually think I found the best answer to be this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y55rLsSNUiM

Answer (score 1):

This is a common scenario in real life,where you want to wait for the first fetch is finished and then do the next fetch.

Please check out the new codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/p92ylrymkj

I used generator when you do fetch request. The data is retrieved in the correct order. After you click fetch data button, go to console and have a look.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very nice. I'm torn between accepting yours or Doğancan answer. The great thing about yours is generators and a running example. But it would have been awesome had you used hooks, instead of `function* steps` inside component render. I'm not sure one will realistically benefit from using raw generators over async/await without some abstraction layer such as redux-saga (takeLatest for cancellation etc.), unless you're hardcore at them, but I did find https://github.com/neurosnap/use-cofx - as someone that obviously knows generators, do you have an opinion on cofx/useCofx.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you face this problem because of poor implementation of a fetch hook and the example is too basic for us to understand. You should make it clear if you'll use job, collegues and person in the same component. If so, it's always wiser to separate them.

That being said, let me give you an example of my own fetch hook:

```
const { loading, error, value } = useResource<Person>(getPerson, personId)
```

I have such a hook, which has it's own state for loading, error, value etc.
It takes two arguments:
 - fetch method
 - fetch method argument

Having such a structure, you can chain your resources together.
useResource implementation is just creating a state and in useEffect, checking if property change etc. If it changed, it calls the fetch method.

Comment: I guess you may be right, if it works with passing down a second argument from your hook param down to the useEffect hook inside it - so that `personId` is the second argument of the `useEffect` inside `useResource`, like `useEffect(() => {},[personId])`. Haven't checked if that works, but if if I understand you right, that is your suggestion, right?

Comment: Not like that. useEffect is executed whenever component is updated. Which means, personId might have been changed in any execution. In a regular react component, what you'd do in componentDidUpdate method? You'd check if you already have state value for personId = 1 (example). If you don't have it, you'd fetch it for id 1. In next iteration, let's say you have personId = 2. Same check would result in another fetch. This logic is pretty generic and can be written in your fetch hook (useResource).

Comment: In the end, it'd be like this: useEffect(() => { if (fetchProperty !== oldFetchProperty) fetch() }). Of course with better equals check with either JSON.stringify or an identifier key.